# how to do speech to text in lua?

Tags: macos, lua, terminal

i have a text writer program, but i think it needs a speech to text system or function but, i am just wondering if it can be done.
**this is my program**

```
io.write("file name?:")
local file=io.read()
os.execute("clear;clear;clear;clear;clear;")
if os.execute("test -e Desktop/"..file) == true then
    os.execute("rm -f Desktop/"..file)
end
local p = {}
while true do
  io.write("-")
  local u = io.read()
  if u ~= "" then
    table.insert(p,u)
  else
    break
  end
end
print("saveing...")
local ty=io.open("Desktop/"..file,"w+")
for i,ie in ipairs(p) do
  ty:write(ie,"\n")
  os.execute("sleep 0.1")
  ty:flush()
end
print("saved")
ty:close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lua alone this is a tricky thing to do. I suggest something like C# or Java. However C# might be easier to use than java. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx

If you still want to use lua, you can also use lua and C# together. Here is a link to help get you started: https://github.com/NLua/NLua

Hope the best

Comment: thanks it answers my question but due to that all my research and data is in lua/termanal bash I will try to make due. but thanks for the help

Comment: what about bash?

Comment: I haven't used bash, but this might help: https://gist.github.com/meskarune/80d208ac4e43dcc70e1c